# Converting KMZ/KML to SHP (3D objects)

Tags: shapefile, convert, 3d, kmz

I have 3D buildings in .kmz file. I can see them in Google Earth, but I cannot import them to ArcGIS. What I've tried until now:

1. I saved it as a .kml file in GoogleEarth and then try to convert the .kml with DNR Garmin to a .shp file. This doesn't work for me. I get zero objects.
2. I also tried [Kml2Shp Online](http://www.zonums.com/online/kml2shp.php) but that also doesn't work. I uploaded my .kmz file successfully but then I cannot continue - it says there is no objects...

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You could try the ogr2ogr tool. I am not sure how it works with 3D...

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS can read KML files and since 9.3 also KMZ via the Data Interoperability Extension.  From version 10 you must install this separately.  The basic version of DI extension does not require a special licence and certainly lets you read GML and (from memory) I think it also reads KML.  I have been used to having the full version so I forget where the free version starts and stops.

For a non-ArcGIS solution [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14180/which-windows-gis-editors-support-the-creation-of-3d-shapefiles-besides-arcgis-w) should help as it is related to your question and suggests other tools you could try.

However, the shapefile format only supports 2.5D and so you couldn't import proper 3D features to the shapefile format anyway.  For that you will need something like PostGIS 2.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your 3D KML to collada (.dae) a **Google Earth Model** - using Google Sketchup
http://sketchup.google.com/download/

Then you can import this **MODEL** into ArcGIS with ArcScene.

Here is a youtube video showing how this can be done.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udhm3yxVinc